# Templated operator[]... possible? Useful?

Tags: c++, templates

Could you have:

```
template <class T>
const T &operator[] (unsigned int x)
```

My thinking was if you have a `map<string,string>` it would be nice to have a wrapper class which lets you do:

```
obj["IntVal"]="12";
obj["StringVal"]="Test";

int i = obj["IntVal"];
```

How close to this can we actually get in C++? Is it worth the pain?

Comment: Overloaded functions cannot differ only in the return type. So it would not be straightforward, I think.

Comment: For what it's worth, I once did something like this and ended up with syntax like `int i = obj["IntVal"].as<int>()`. Or maybe `int i = obj.get<int>("IntVal")`. You could use implicit conversions to get the syntax you'd like, but that will open up other worlds of pain.

Comment: Another suggestion for a syntax (that I have used before and is also used in pqxx) is instead of returning the value pass it as parameter and allow the compiler to do type deduction: `obj[key].to(var)`. This removes the need for the explicit type in the method call.

Answer (score 5):

You can also do

```
class Class {
  struct Proxy {
    template<typename T> T as() { ... }
    template<typename T> operator T() { return as<T>(); }
  private:
    Proxy(...) { ... }
    Proxy(Proxy const&); // noncopyable
    Proxy &operator=(Proxy const&);
    friend class Class;
  };

public:
  Proxy operator[](std::string const& s) { ... }
};

Class a;
int i = a["foo"];
int i = a["foo"].as<int>();
```

`T` will be deduced to whatever the to be initialized object is. And you are not allowed to copy the proxy. That said, i prefer an explicit `as<T>` function like another one proposed too.

Comment: Assignment using `operator[]` doesn't seem possible using this method. Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 4):

You can't - in:

```
int i = obj["IntVal"];
```

the actual type of T can't be inferred from the context since the return type isn't part of the function signature.

Moreover, storing integer values as strings is not considered as best practices, due to memory and performance considerations ;-)

Comment: @Seb A good answer, which I hope I have improved with my edit. If not, feel free to roll it back.

Comment: You did :-) As a newcomer, I didn't know you could use rich text formatting, sorry

Comment: No need to apologise - to format code, select it and then use the 1010 button above the text entry area. Don't try to use HTML tags.

Comment: "storing integer values as strings is not considered as best practices"... well of course, but it still happens in many cases, any time XML or text-mode files are used for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Not worth it.

Templating the return type means you'd have to explicitly specify the template parameter when you call it. Something like this, maybe I have the syntax wrong:

```
int i = obj.operator[]<int>("IntVal");
```

C++ does not deduce template parameters from what you assign the result of the call to, only from the parameters you call the function with.

So you might as well just define a normal function:

```
int i = obj.get<int>("IntVal");
```

Or in this case, either do this or implement `get` using this:

```
int i = boost:lexical_cast<int>(obj["IntVal"]);
```

As Amit says, you could define `operator[]` to return a type which can be converted either to `int` or to other types. Then your example code can be made to compile without the explicit lexical_cast.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [boost variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html)? Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you wrote in your sample code doesn't match the question.  Right now, you only have the return type templated.

But if you wanted to do something like:

```
template <class T>
const T &operator[const T& x]
```

that's valid, though maybe not terribly useful.

Answer (score 0):

A map already provides an overloaded `operator[]` that does most of what you want. The thing you seem to want that's missing is implicit conversion from a string that happens to contain digits to an integer. One of the fundamental characteristics of C++ is static typing, which says that shouldn't be allowed -- so it's not. It'll be happy to do that conversion if you want, but you'll have to ask for it:

```
int i = lexical_cast<int>(obj["IntVal"]);
```

Alternatively, you could create a string-like class that supported implicit conversion to `int`. Personally, I'd advise against that. I don't object to implicit conversions nearly as strongly as many people do, but that still strikes me as a pretty lousy idea, at least for most general use.